# "Not Available" Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Dear All,
When I use a table from database, if data is not available in table. I will use if and else conditions like

```
<% if @tables.blank? %>
  <p> Not available</p>
<% else %>
  blaaa blaa
<% end %>
```

It works fine. Now I need to apply the same thing for connected tables. If data is available in first table tables and not available in benches. How I can apply??

I tried like this

```
<% @tables.each do |table| %>
  <% if table.benches.blank? %>
    <p> Not available</p>
  <% else %>
    blaaa blaa
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

... But its not working. Kindly give me suggestions.

Comment: In second example you missed one `<% end %>`. What error do you get? Can you show your models and how you load `@table` in both cases?

Comment: how that is not working. You have a error raise ?

Comment: @Shingara:No error... Everything working fine... If I apply the above method... It shows none, if no results in table. Instead of that I need to display Not "Available".

Comment: @klew: Sorry, I included in the script. here only i missed when copying. Now i edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear All, Its working... when i apply like this...

```
<% if @tables.blank? %>
  <p> Not available</p>
<% else %>
  <% @tables.each do |table| %>
    <% table.benches.each do |bench| %>
      <% if bench.column.blank? %>
        <p> Not available</p>
      <% else %>
        blaaa blaa
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for everyone who participated in this Question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but maybe this will help you.

```
<% if @tables.blank? %>
  <p> Not available</p>
<% else %>
  <% @tables.each do |table| %>
    <% if table.benches.blank? %>
      <p> Not available</p>
    <% else %>
      blaaa blaa
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It isn't printing anything? Nor "not availble" nor "blaaa blaa"? Please attach code from controller where you initialize `@table` and code for related models.

Comment: Does the code you're using include the `<% if @tables.blank? %>` part? My guess is that what's happening is that `@tables` is blank/empty, which means that the code inside the `each` block is not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#empty?`.

```
<% @tables.each do |table| %>
  <% if table.benches.empty? %>
    <p> Not available</p>
  <% else %>
    blaaa blaa
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `blank?` and `empty?` works similar and in this example should give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this:

```
<% unless table.benches.exists? %>
  <p> Not available</p>
<% else %>
  blaaa blaa
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if/else` **must** output one or the other... make sure you check your HTML source code (not just browser view) to see if the output isn't hiding somewhere inside a tag.